# How to jump from one tab's stack navigator to the screen of the tab's parent navigator in react navigation ( v1 )

Tags: react-navigation

**MainNavigator**

```
const MainNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Start:{ screen:Start },
    Login:{ screen:Login },
    mainFlow:{
      screen: TabNavigator({
        Profile: { screen: Profile },
        List: { screen: List },
        MenuStack: { screen: StackNavigator({
          Menu: {screen: Menu},
          OpenChannel: { screen: OpenChannel },
          OpenChannelCreate: { screen: OpenChannelCreate },
          Chat: { screen: Chat },
          Member: { screen: Member },
          BlockUser: { screen: BlockUser },
          GroupChannel: { screen: GroupChannel },
          GroupChannelInvite: { screen: GroupChannelInvite },
        },{
          initialRouteName: 'Menu',
          headerMode: 'none',
        })}
      },{
        initialRouteName: 'Profile'
      })
    }
  },{
    initialRouteName: 'Start',
  }
);
```

How can I jump from Menu of mainFlow's menuStack to Login Screen of MainNavigator . 
I've tried some ways like passing parents navigation to child navigation as params but I failed to pass navigation from tabNavigation to child StackNavigation... 
I really need your help!